# Alignment issue in Android EditText

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

Please have a look at the following code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Form" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/heightLabel"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/height"
           /> 

       <EditText 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/heightLabel"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:hint=""
           />

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I need this `EditText` to be displayed right next to the `TextView`, with it's appropriate size. But instead, it is displaying in no where. I don't even see it! Please help!

Comment: "with it's appropriate size" You are using `wrap_content` and no default text... What is the appropriate size? Try using `match_parent` or an attribute like `minWidth` or `ems` to define its size.

Comment: @Sam: What should I pass into the "ems" as parameters?

Comment: `ems` is literally the number of capital M's that you want to fit in the EditText. You use _either_ `minWidth` or `ems` but _not_ both, since they are conflicting settings.

Comment: @Sam: Great. Please provide your comment as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `wrap_content` but no default text. So if the EditText is visible, it will be quite small. You need to define an appropriate size yourself. Try using `match_parent` as the width or adding an attribute like `minWidth` or `ems`.